# Prevent RabbitMQ erl_crash.dump files?

Tags: rabbitmq, distributed-computing

Whenever I start my RabbitMQ 2.8.4 server on my Mac laptop (OS X 10.9.5) manually, I use this command:

```
/usr/local/rabbitmq_server/sbin/rabbitmq-server -detached
```

However, whenever I do this, the server will start but a file named "erl_crash.dump" file is created in whatever directory I run the command from.

Is there any way to start the server in the background without littering my hard drive with these dump files?  I've searched the Internet and the RabbitMQ documentation for an answer but couldn't find anything.  I also didn't see anything pertinent in the rabbitmq.config.example file.

Comment: Any reason why you use such an old version of RabbitMQ. An `erl_crash.dump` was solved on Mac on a recent release.

Comment: haywire, you have nothing better to do?  :-)